CF7 for radio buttons only, ok?
I want to use Contact Form 7 only to use the radio buttons, so this form doesn't need to be send. That mean no submit button. There is a javascript to display content when a radio button is selected.
We just added reCachat hidden to avoid anyone send messages.
Could be this solution overworked, insecure ? or any other issue ?
Thanks

Seems like overkill to have CF7 installed just so you can have radio buttons... ...are you not able to apply radio buttons any other way?  Since you're already adding JS, you can hide the submit button and then make sure that it does nothing when clicked, I guess.
